# How to understand that an operator is a distribution?

Tags: distribution-theory

Let $T:= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} i^{\alpha}(\delta_{1/i} - \delta_{-1/i})$. I want to find the values of $\alpha$ such that this operator is, in fact, a distribution in $D'(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\})$.

Clearly it is linear but now I have two problems.

1. The sum is infinite (but maybe I can only take the partial sums and then the limit, however I'm stuck).
2. We are working in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Could this fact rise up problems? (For example I can't take compact subsets like $[-a,a]$ in which I usally worked).

So, how to prove that for all compact $K \subset\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ there exists $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $c > 0 $ such that 
$$ |\langle T,\phi\rangle | \leq c \Vert \phi\Vert_{C_K^p}? $$

Answer (score 1):

Your second concern is actually the key to resolve your first.

Compact sets of $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ must be disjoint from some open neighborhood of $0,$ so for test functions $\phi$ supported on compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\},$ the operator $T$ applied to $\phi$ becomes a finite sum (whose "size" is dependent only on $K$)

Comment: So, if I take $K \subset \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ to be compact, then there is a "step" $i_K$ such that for $ i > i_K$ the elements $ 1/i$ and $-1/i$ are no longer in $K$, hence I can stop the sum at this $i_K$.

Comment: @DavideMotta Right.  That's exactly what I'm saying.

Comment: Hence $|\langle T,\phi\rangle | \leq 2 \sum_{i=0}^{i_K} i^{\alpha} \Vert \phi \Vert_{C^0}$. Right?

Comment: But this leads me to say that $T$ is a distribution for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and this sounds odd. I supposed $T$ is a distribution for every $\alpha < -1$. What can you say about this $\alpha$?

Comment: Hrmmm... maybe I don't understand your notation?  Is $C_K^p$ not a class of test functions supported on $K$?  Or perhaps $c$ needs to be global rather than dependent on $K$? (this last one would "force" $\alpha < -1$)

Comment: Yes it is. The above inequality should hold for every $\phi \in C_{K}^{\infty}$ and I think $c$ could be dependent on $K$. So, in conclusion, if i'm looking for $c$ global this leads $\alpha < -1$, otherwise $T$ is a distribution for every $\alpha$ right?

Comment: By the definition of distribution $c$ depends on $K$ so $\alpha$ doesn't affect this $T$

Comment: Perhaps if I call $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n i^{\alpha}(\delta_{1/i} - \delta_{-1/i})$ and i want to find those $\alpha$ such that $S_n$ converges to a distribution $S$ in the whole $D'(\mathbb{R})$ i will find $\alpha <-1$.